# Update Data Attribute via URL Parameter

Tags: javascript, html, url, parameters, attributes

I'm trying to get this div:

```
<div id=form data-form-id=z0y9x8 data-user-id=a1b2c3></div>
```

to modify the data-user-id from the url:

```
https://example.com/?user=d4e5f6
```

so it results in this:

```
<div id=form data-form-id=z0y9x8 data-user-id=d4e5f6></div>
```

Here's the code I'm using, but things aren't connecting properly.

```
<script>    
    function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
    }
    var user = getUrlVars()["user"];         
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    form.setAttribute("data-user-id", user);
</script>
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: Updated with Barmar & Tim's suggestions. Still no dice though.

Comment: Don't put quotes around `user` if you want the variable value.

Comment: Couple issues. One, you are missing a closing bracket for the `getUrlVars()` function, it needs to be after `return vars;`.  Second, as Barmar commented, you need to remove the quotes from the user variable in `form.setAttribute("data-user-id", 'user');`

Comment: @ShamrockJedd, works fine on my end.  What error are you seeing? https://jsfiddle.net/tcmph4s6/

Comment: When inspecting the page the data-user-id isn't updating to the user variable in the URL. The only error I see in the console is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute') at "https://example.com/?user=d4e5f6"`.